# What is wrong with constructor function? Browser says that it isn't defined when i try to create new object

Tags: javascript, oop

this is my code

```
"use strict"

function Сalculator() {
  this.read = function() {
    this.first = +prompt();
    this.second = +prompt();
  };
  this.sum = function() {
    return this.first + this.second;
  };
  this.mul = function() {
    return this.first * this.second;
  };
}

let calculator = new Calculator();
calculator.read();
alert(calculator.sum());

// But this code is perfectly correct
function Calculator() {
  this.read = function() {
    this.a = +prompt('a?', 0);
    this.b = +prompt('b?', 0);
  };

  this.sum = function() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  };

  this.mul = function() {
    return this.a * this.b;
  };
}
let calculator = new Calculator();
calculator.read();

alert("Sum=" + calculator.sum());
alert("Mul=" + calculator.mul());
```

I didn't noticed any difference between them

Comment: I think you want to use `class` not `function` you can't do `new SomeFunction()` but `new SomeClass()`

Comment: I can't imagine that the second code works

Comment: I don't know about classes and it realization on JS. I only know about constructor functions at this moment.

Comment: Constructor functions are only used in classes. So there is no sense in your comment

Comment: You have a Cyrillic 'С' in the `function Сalculator()`, not a Latin one.

Comment: Ahahah ty, code works! I tried 2 hours to find the mistake.